# 7-Zip source compliation issue

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to compile the console application in 7-Zip source code. But i get this error below,

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Console, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>.\Debug\7zCrcOpt.obj : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x268
1>Build log was saved at "file://f:\7z920\CPP\7zip\UI\Console\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Console - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Any help on this? thanks

Comment: Do a complete rebuild?  Manually delete all generated files and rebuild?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you somehow got a corrupted object file. You can remove this by using the "Clean" option from the "Build" menu (and then try building again).

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Main Menu -> Build -> Rebuild Solution

Answer (score 0):

Download and extract 7z1701.7z from http://www.7-zip.org/download.html

```
c:\> c:\visual-studio-10\vc\vcvarsall.bat 
  > devenv \CPP\7zip\UI\Console\Console.dsw
    [Some Gui conversion]
  > devenv c:\src\7zip3\CPP\7zip\UI\Console\Console.dsw
    [error as in question]
c:\7zip\CPP\7zip\> nmake NEW_COMPILER=1 MY_STATIC_LINK=1
    SUCCESS  .. all the exe built.
```